# What manga is this page used to advertise for scanlators from?

Tags: happy-cafe

What is the name of the manga below, the text has been changed by a translator team to help find new translators.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Happy Cafe**

[image: Cover]

> Romance and happiness blossoms at the Happy Cafe! Uru takes her mother's remarriage as an opportunity to work part time at the Happy Cafe. There, she befriends Ichirou and Shindou, two of the most unsociable guys she's ever met! To make matters worse, it turns out that Uru is not exactly meant for the waitressing world, as she's a huge klutz. But as this hilarious shoujo tale unfolds, true happiness,and even true love, lurks just around the corner. [source](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6599093-happy-cafe-vol-1)

this particular image you have posted is from the 11th volume of this manga.
for more informations about his manga [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Cafe) or [here](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6599093-happy-cafe-vol-1)

Comment: Welcome to the Anime/Manga SE. Could you perhaps expand a bit on some details of the manga?

Comment: Thanks, its my first post here so i am not sure what kind of details i might provide, is it enough to add the wikipedia link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Cafe

Comment: generally, what I've seen people do is either summarize the synopsis (I've done this for some series I've never actually followed) or perhaps copy-paste one from a site (with the source included). It's also good to include a link to Wikipedia or similar sites. [This](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/1103/2604) might be helpful (although personally, I've never included an image in my answer).

Comment: In cases like this, it's also useful if you manage to find a copy of the original manga page and post that in too.